# Independent collections, proving independence of its generated $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

in my way to understand independence in a theoretical way I face this problem that knock me out haha, I'm totally lost here so any help is really welcome.

**Problem:**

Let $\mathcal{M_{1}}$ and $\mathcal{M_{2}}$ two collection of independent sets. Suppose that if $A,B \in \mathcal{M_{i}}$ for $i=1,2$ then $A\cap B \in \mathcal{M_{i}}$. Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{M_{1}})$ is independent of $\sigma(\mathcal{M_{2}})$.

Thanks so much for all your help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy consequence of Dynkin's $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem. First fix $B \in \mathcal M_2$ and consider $\{A \in \sigma (\mathcal M_1): P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\}$. Application of $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem tells you that this class contains all sets in $\sigma (\mathcal M_1)$ (because it is a $\lambda$ system containing the $\pi$ system $\mathcal M_1$). Now fix $A \in \sigma (\mathcal M_1)$ and consider $\{B \in \sigma (\mathcal M_2): P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)\}$. Another application of $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem finishes the proof.

Comment: Wow, that theorem is everywhere. The thing is that since we havent been taught exactly that theorem we can not use it. So I'm trying to solve this only using algebras, sigma-algebras and monotone class theorem which are the things that I was taught :(